# Algebraic Geometry: Let $\varphi: k[X,Y] \rightarrow k(t)$ defined by $\varphi (f(X,Y)) = f(\frac{1-t^2}{t^2+1},\frac{2t}{t^2+1})$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ideals

I need show that $Ker \varphi = (X^2 + Y^2 - 1)$ . Clearly $(X^2 + Y^2 -1 ) \subset Ker \varphi$. To show the other inclusion, I did:

Let $f(X,Y) \in Ker \varphi$. Then

$$ f(X,Y) = (X^2 + Y^2 - 1)q(X,Y) + r(X,Y)$$

such that either $r(X,Y)=0$ or $r(X,Y)=g(X)+h(X)Y$. If $r(X,Y)=0$, the proof ends. Then, suppose that $r(X,Y)=g(X)+h(X)Y$.

Since that $\varphi(r(X,Y)) = 0$, $r(X,Y) \in Ker \varphi$; that is:

$$g(\frac{1-t^2}{t^2+1})+h(\frac{1-t^2}{t^2+1})(\frac{2t}{t^2+1}) = 0$$

The hint to end, is look on for the degree of this expression, but I can not see the contradiction.

Comment: Think about the total degree of $g$. What is it when $gIx)=x$? $g(x)= x^2$? Now recall that two nonzero rational expressions of different total degrees cannot sum to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picking up where you left off, let $g(X), h(X) \in k[X]$ be nonzero polynomials such that

$$g\left(\frac{1-t^{2}}{t^{2}+1}\right) + h\left(\frac{1-t^{2}}{t^{2}+1}\right)\frac{2t}{t^{2}+1} = 0$$

Clearing denominators by multiplying by a suitable power of $t^{2}+1$, there exist non-negative integers $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$(t^{2}+1)^{m}g(1-t^{2}) + (t^{2}+1)^{n}h(1-t^{2})2t = 0$$

whence

$$(t^{2}+1)^{m}g(1-t^{2}) = -(t^{2}+1)^{n}h(1-t^{2})2t $$

Now, whatever $n, m$ are, $(t^{2}+1)^{m}$ and $(t^{2}+1)^{n}$ are polynomials of even degree in $t$. Likewise, whatever the degrees of $g, h$ are, $g(1-t^{2})$ and $h(1-t^{2})$ are also of even degree in $t$, so $(t^{2}+1)^{m}g(1-t^{2})$ and $(t^{2}+1)^{n}h(1-t^{2})$ are both of even degree in $t$. But then this means that the LHS of the equation above has even degree in $t$, whereas the RHS has odd degree in $t$, which gives the desired contradiction.

Comment: (Clearly, one of $n, m$ above can be taken to be $0$, but doing so doesn't improve the clarity of the proof IMO, so I've ignored this modest simplification.)

Comment: Is $k$ supposed a field ?  Is there a restricted characteristic ?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E.: I presumed (perhaps erroneously) that $k$ is a field, of characterstic not equal to $2$, though I think that this argument goes through fine even if $k$ is not assumed to be a field (with the same assumptions on the characteristic).